# How do I specify the velocity and threshold, using jQuery Hammer?

Tags: hammer.js

How do I specify the velocity and threshold, using jQuery Hammer?

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $(function(){ 
    var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
    Hammer(myElement).on("swipeleft", function() {
      console.log("drag left");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you still need the answer, but your can change it like this:

```js
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
mc.add( new Hammer.Swipe({ velocity: 0.1, threshold: 0 }) );
```